# Assigning function to element of a vector R

Tags: r

I am trying to assign a function to every row of a vector. However it does not work properly. I tried many things as using parse, eval, etc but i do no find my mistake. I think for you it should not be too complicated. Here's the code

```
quartale <- c("2014", "2015")
test <- c("arnaud", "elio", "pascal", "david", "senior")

for(i in 1:5){
  assign(paste("meldungen.", quartale[1], "[",i, "]", sep=""),nchar(test[i]))                                   
}
```

Thus, I would like finally to have a vector

```
meldungen.arnaud = 6,4,6,5,6
```

Comment: Probably, you need `nchar(test[i])`

Comment: You never close the round brackets related with `for`.

Comment: Yeah sorry guys you are right, i corrected the typos. However, it's the assigning function that does not work with the [i]

Comment: Try `meldungen.arnaud <- nchar(test)`

Comment: yes, it won't.  If you *really* want to do this you need to use `eval()`.  But there's probably a better way to do what you want to do ...

Comment: actually I think they want `assign(get(paste0("meldungen.",arnaud[1])),nchar(test))`

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. However, I really need to use the indexion i. because this part is a part of a bigger project. Do you have still an idea with get? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
nam <- paste("meldungen.", quartale[1], sep="")
assign(nam, nchar(test))

> meldungen.2014
[1] 6 4 6 5 6
```

Not really sure what are you looking for but there is some advice:

This code:

```
for (i in 1:5){ assign((paste0("meldungen.", test[i])), nchar(test[i]))}
```

gives you

```
> meldungen.arnaud
[1] 6
```

respectively

```
> meldungen.elio
[1] 4
```

This code gives you what you described in your post:

```
> assign((paste0("meldungen.", test[1])), nchar(test))
> meldungen.arnaud
[1] 6 4 6 5 6
```

Hope this helps